# Debugging an python django project

Tags: python, django

I am python developer and follow an single python django sample project.

Now I face an error, still could not find the solution:

```
"IntegrityError at /blog/1/comments/new/
NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_comment.author_id"
```

I hope a helpful advice on this problem
thanks...

```
"models.py":

class Comment(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.PROTECT)  #20190613 added some code by jpanda 'on_delete'
        author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_constraint= False)
        message = models.TextField()

        def get_absolute_url(self):

                return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.post_id])

"views.py":

class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm

def form_valid(self, form):
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = self.kwargs['post_pk'])
        comment.author = self.request.user
        comment.save()
        return super(CommentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

  comment_new = CommentCreateView.as_view()
```

After adding the commnents in comment form, I have to add the comments into the posting panel, but there is an error like above:
    I don't know the reason exactly:

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. Is that how it is in your real code? If so that form_valid isn't even part of the class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although there are many things unclear about your question. But I am assuming this error is happening when you are running the `./manage.py makemigrations` command. The error is because the database requires you to have a value for `author` field for all the rows. It is because the `null` parameter in `models.ForeignKey()` is `False` by default. Meaning it doesn't allow `null` values.

Now obviously, you're not entering any value or data for the fields as of running `makemigrations` command. But this can happen when you try adding extra fields to an already migrated model(or table) which contains some entries. So when you add that extra field which in your case might be `author`, it updates the table with that extra entry. But the earlier rows don't have any value for that field. Meaning they would be `null`. But as  the default value is `null=False` you get this error.

If you allow your `author` ForeignKey as `null=True` this will solve the problem.  Meaning the already present entries can have `null` values.

```
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_constraint= False)
```

**Another Solution**:

If you're just doing a sample project and the data in your database is not that important to you. You can also delete the already existing tables or clean the whole database. Check this [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html) for reference.